How to make reusable ElevatedButton with onPressed property on Flutter
I am trying to make a scalable Button widget using flutter, all the property is working except onPressed which required a VoidCallback data type, what is wrong in here
code:
// ignore_for_file: public_member_api_docs, sort_constructors_first
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

// ignore: must_be_immutable
class PrimaryButton extends StatelessWidget {
  // NOTE: if VoidCallback + required this.onPressedData is uncommented then route error
  // VoidCallback onPressedData;
  String textButtonData;
  PrimaryButton({
    super.key,
    // required this.onPressedData,
    required this.textButtonData,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ElevatedButton(
      //TODO: implement onPressed to each button
      onPressed: () {},
      // onPressedData,
      style: ButtonStyle(
        fixedSize: WidgetStatePropertyAll(Size(368, 49),),
        backgroundColor: WidgetStatePropertyAll(
          Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primaryContainer
          ),
      ),
      child: Text(
        textButtonData,
        style: TextStyle(
          color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onPrimaryContainer,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          fontSize: 18)),
    );
  }
}

I tried using the commented solution but it did not work due to something

You do not actually need to declare it as VoidCallBack simply change it to this:
also declare it as final and git rid of immutability warning, hope it works for you
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class PrimaryButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final void Function() onPressedData;
  final String textButtonData;
  PrimaryButton({
    super.key,
    required this.onPressedData,
    required this.textButtonData,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ElevatedButton(
      //TODO: implement onPressed to each button
      onPressed: onPressedData,
      // onPressedData,
      style: ButtonStyle(
        fixedSize: WidgetStatePropertyAll(Size(368, 49),),
        backgroundColor: WidgetStatePropertyAll(
          Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primaryContainer
          ),
      ),
      child: Text(
        textButtonData,
        style: TextStyle(
          color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onPrimaryContainer,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          fontSize: 18)),
    );
  }
}


ah thanks Hassan, no wonder it does not work

what does final actually do in this code?

you are extending a stateless widget class which extends a Widget class which marked as immutable , but you are declaring its instances without final keyword that's means it could change during run time without rebuilding the widget again which is a clear violation for classes marked as @immutable constraints , so just declare it as final and also add const keyword before the constructor function to avoid the warning , it will be like this:    final void Function() onPressedData;  -- and const before constructor
